# R boxplot vs ggplot2 geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Why are the boxplots so different?

```
boxplot(loan.part.value ~ platform, p2p)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(p2p, aes(loan.part.value, platform)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

(I redacted the tick labels.)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the order is switched in one of your plots.  In `boxplot` the formula is `y ~ x` where as `ggplot2` has the first positional argument of `x`.